# Qt QToolBar not functioning properly

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having a problem getting my toolbar to show a border or even be able to become movable. I'm unable to solve the problem, I'm new to Qt, so any help will be really appreciated.

My Code:

```
QWidget *view = new QTextEdit(this);
QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout(this);

fileToolBar = new QToolBar(this);
fileToolBar->addAction("file");
fileToolBar->setMovable(true);

vbox->addWidget(fileToolBar);
vbox->addWidget(view);
vbox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);
vbox->setSpacing(0);
setLayout(vbox);
```

Here is a picture of what it looks like. I have four different instances, located on my app, that I'm splitting using QSplitter's.  Each one has a toolbar.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qtoolbar.html#movable-prop) says about tool bars being movable:

> This property only makes sense if the toolbar is in a QMainWindow.

So that if you want to create a movable tool bar you need to consider using `QMainwWindow` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I just tried to make it movable to see if it was functioning properly since the borders were not showing up.  I'm more concerned with the borders not showing.  I copied exactly what another person has implemented, but got a different result.  You can find it here http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3647

Comment: @Wallace, I believe that person still uses `QMainWindow`, no?

Comment: The title of his thread is "Adding a Toolbar to children widget of a QSplitter" and from the code it doesn't look like it.  But, I'm new to Qt and could be wrong.